# Install Anaconda Navigator with Miniforge (Mac with M1 chip)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, apple-m1

I have a MacBook with an M1 chip and have installed miniforge since this will run natively on the M1 chip.

**Question**: How do I install Anaconda Navigator so that it uses the miniforge environment when I use it to launch Spyder and Jupyterlab? Or is this currently not possible?

If I run `conda install anaconda-navigator`, I get a `PackagesNotFoundError`. I believe this is expected.

If I understand correctly, one alternative is to install both miniconda (currently x86 only) and miniforge (e.g. [Jeff Heaton's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2qlou7n7MA)).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please ask only one question at a time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/248627).

Comment: Anaconda navigator is from the defaults (main) channel. I guess it's not possible but that's a good idea to make available on conda-forge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as at the time(June 30, 2022) of writing this answer anaconda navigator was not yet available on M1 MacBook pro because the MacOs does not yet support Qt
so yes, you may have to install the mini-forge which is your best alternative if you have to choose between miniconda, anaconda or mini-forge
https://www.anaconda.com/blog/new-release-anaconda-distribution-now-supporting-m1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm running an M1 with miniforge and I installed navigator.

```
conda install anaconda-navigator
```

I used it to backup my apple metal environment.  Works just fine.